# Magento 2 configurable product

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

How to identity configurable product in magento frontend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest what to figure out if a product is a configurable product on the frontend is to view the page source and look for the body tag"

> body class='page-product-configurable..'

If you are trying to figure out if a product is configurable in a phtml file

> if ($product->getTypeId() === 'configurable')

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below link -It will help you.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html

Please see step 3 carefully -